# How to see the false positive cases with bloom index in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, index

I have tried to reproduce a false positive but it is almost imposible to check for an example in my database. Thats what I did.

First create the index

```
CREATE EXTENSION bloom;
```

Then create the table and insert some data:

```
CREATE TABLE bar (id int, dept int, id2 int, id3 int, id4 int, id5 int,id6 int,id7 int,details text, zipcode int);
INSERT INTO bar_bloom SELECT (random() * 1000000)::int, (random() * 1000000)::int,
                       (random() * 1000000)::int,(random() * 1000000)::int,(random() * 1000000)::int,(random() * 1000000)::int,
                       (random() * 1000000)::int,(random() * 1000000)::int,md5(g::text), floor(random()* (20000-9999 + 1) + 9999)
from generate_series(1,100*1e6) g;
```

Then using explain analyze to see if it is using the index:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from bar_bloom where id4 = 998475 and zipcode = 11065;
```

And it outputs:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on bar_bloom  (cost=1784320.00..1784324.02 rows=1 width=69) (actual time=1069.203..1641.190 rows=1 loops=1)
Recheck Cond: ((id4 = 998475) AND (zipcode = 11065))
Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 3025320
  Heap Blocks: exact=41040 lossy=36827
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_bloom_bar  (cost=0.00..1784320.00 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1063.738..1063.739 rows=80369 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((id4 = 998475) AND (zipcode = 11065))
Planning Time: 0.076 ms
Execution Time: 1641.775 ms
```

In order to see if these result (which in my database is unique, maybe in other ones because it is random it is not unique) I could see that in a copy of this database with a non-bloom index it is also unique. I have tried to search for a false positive with a couple of queries but I was not able to find anyone.

Is there a way to see the hashes function of each result in order to see which combinations of a search will output the same bite array? I.e. finding a condition which result in a false positive.

Comment: If you are willing to change the code and recompile, you can make it do anything you want to, as long as that is within your coding skills.  It is not really clear what you are trying to do, though.  Are you trying to learn how to program, or trying to figure out whether this bloom index is a practical data structure to use with your data, or what?

Comment: You show the creation of the table and the insertion of the data (but with the wrong name), but not the creation of the index.

Answer (score 1):

You will never get false positive results, since they are removed by the `Index Recheck` during the `Bitmap Heap Scan` phase. If you want to know how many false positives the `Bitmap Index Scan` phase produced, increase `work_mem` until you see no more `lossy` heap blocks, then the `Rows Removed by Index Recheck` will show the desired number.

Comment: So if we reduce the number of the length of bits with:

CREATE INDEX idx_bloom_bar ON bar_bloom USING bloom(id, dept, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, zipcode)
 WITH (length=20, col1=1, col2=1, col3=2);

We will have more false positive results right?

Is there any way to disable de Index Recheck?

Comment: I can answer the second question: no.